# To Check the following emails are spoofed or not

Tags: email-spoofing

Please help me to check whether the following emails are spoofed or not since I'm receiving spoofed emails from bank and other websites I use frequently so I can raise a complaint with the bank.

```
Delivered-To: theon@gmail.com
Received: by 2002:a5d:6191:0:b0:337:4d85:da74 with SMTP id j17csp979050wru;
        Fri, 2 Feb 2024 22:35:20 -0800 (PST)
X-Google-Smtp-Source: AGHT+IFnKkgWs5bsM0JFNvfGvVbLRDHI5MdP71qfRQ1/Q0NLZ3WLiW9NE8TATxMxbap9wR0CfXAs
X-Received: by 2002:a17:902:e882:b0:1d9:7095:7e1f with SMTP id w2-20020a170902e88200b001d970957e1fmr5318328plg.67.1706942120255;
        Fri, 02 Feb 2024 22:35:20 -0800 (PST)
ARC-Seal: i=3; a=rsa-sha256; t=1706942120; cv=pass;
        d=google.com; s=arc-20160816;
        b=LspGFMkX/YCr+hB7XiXIAgGVXL/R2hpFXKrKJhBKrqRIe1F2IOyW5EUwrTrCAo3itw
         bNDllQco6W/jyf6yZXC5QfS9UBZBjSHC+mz/JLh3IaJNDUjwiHavBGCZ3oRn+qFo1DEI
         WP08BGjP1RmC9ny9pohDX9JrRLJ9MRCi8miwjS/ZNHPMO1wJammWU33Zgj975vHdrQNd
         bI6jvceA4xUiIZvoG9ZFk1gPx+zf+ggrGZ6kDW/ToiUh7klg7gO/wRfkCgZGFGJUGUIJ
         Nb6hp2NByLQkoOzYqJltkg1lYGjFo9aOPyAjPwn9G1jhiuiVioNuWTt0Y8zBhRZRG6zg
         kW5w==
ARC-Message-Signature: i=3; a=rsa-sha256; c=relaxed/relaxed; d=google.com; s=arc-20160816;
        h=mime-version:authentication-results-original:content-language
         :accept-language:references:message-id:date:thread-index
         :thread-topic:subject:to:from:dkim-signature:dkim-signature;
        bh=vNWik9gPQj9bKtNXolztInppHglsxL21JrmRBTzr3Vc=;
        fh=X3jwq71fsyqIJwql3B8NrIU5RooAx87P4X31xio3m+E=;
        b=t2K8klDOV4dkZp7+7+YHlTU+DIGgVakhuc0EW0DAZK3oj8aZa8L8THdkr94cSQNR2e
         R/H8aobQu5IryembUKno6N6tXBFVv9r5mUfQbdTR+DXjNPcNo+YzHubQA2osw4F7Sp0w
         HJTABhljwsaDtwcWJ9uwA623+MT+n/1ANpsnU+2q7fv20INmHSFN7TIDoDj4qe/+EWxI
         fYKPOTaCLpdaz7ir381tpi6B/3zBv8lQVrcU9kU0B/G0KmhWx93WIwHqu1HFTEGfKORm
         wyShYVSl7ENY1g1UbkI44wM8U1JW/TUHychnDrNlbzKNg8eN2WDQMr2gGzVOQ/3V4bhn
         nHAg==;
        dara=google.com
ARC-Authentication-Results: i=3; mx.google.com;
       dkim=pass header.i=@hdfcbank.com header.s=selector1 header.b=eq2egeJs;
       dkim=pass header.i=@hdfcbank.com header.s=selector1 header.b=eq2egeJs;
       arc=pass (i=2 dkim=pass dkdomain=hdfcbank.com dmarc=pass fromdomain=hdfcbank.com);
       spf=pass (google.com: domain of preferredbanking@hdfcbank.com designates 2a01:111:f403:2021::601 as permitted sender) smtp.mailfrom=Preferredbanking@hdfcbank.com;
       dmarc=pass (p=REJECT sp=REJECT dis=NONE) header.from=hdfcbank.com
Return-Path: <Preferredbanking@hdfcbank.com>
Received: from IND01-BMX-obe.outbound.protection.outlook.com (mail-bmxind01on20601.outbound.protection.outlook.com. [2a01:111:f403:2021::601])
        by mx.google.com with ESMTPS id ix3-20020a170902f80300b001d9586d5d78si2834193plb.233.2024.02.02.22.35.19
        for <theon@gmail.com>
        (version=TLS1_2 cipher=ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256 bits=128/128);
        Fri, 02 Feb 2024 22:35:20 -0800 (PST)
Received-SPF: pass (google.com: domain of preferredbanking@hdfcbank.com designates 2a01:111:f403:2021::601 as permitted sender) client-ip=2a01:111:f403:2021::601;
Authentication-Results: mx.google.com;
       dkim=pass header.i=@hdfcbank.com header.s=selector1 header.b=eq2egeJs;
       dkim=pass header.i=@hdfcbank.com header.s=selector1 header.b=eq2egeJs;
       arc=pass (i=2 dkim=pass dkdomain=hdfcbank.com dmarc=pass fromdomain=hdfcbank.com);
       spf=pass (google.com: domain of preferredbanking@hdfcbank.com designates 2a01:111:f403:2021::601 as permitted sender) smtp.mailfrom=Preferredbanking@hdfcbank.com;
       dmarc=pass (p=REJECT sp=REJECT dis=NONE) header.from=hdfcbank.com
ARC-Seal: i=2; a=rsa-sha256; s=arcselector9901; d=microsoft.com; cv=pass; b=bYfur0SKVE8OeucbJ6JQr2nWDJNpIJCrcn25D/+1WG7epmpQRDc15pN9Tm7ihjTh15YhnnXTgKUE5WRPIYtd8mbS4mq+hw82p7qpvIAc+x2hZabMAgl6kW2yaIROxuxF+QN5LUPgWsjno1QuGujQphjpQGTUD3XRp+DcPzR0299Kb0tSwHa8tnrYY9hhSvYFl56JsXBCWhB4IosDPUdPio6xVJXuMhy+kCK/CQjsD7wZ5aJLmtPzHkRzbtMsK5LC9QdJryvdA3Psqmg8lxQVG4+3yd66f5FOCv3P5MaKnWHhz70fj2t/dbArUT6Zohq6pneCdvt6ncvDxxs3Ofu6Cg==
ARC-Message-Signature: i=2; a=rsa-sha256; c=relaxed/relaxed; d=microsoft.com; s=arcselector9901; h=From:Date:Subject:Message-ID:Content-Type:MIME-Version:X-MS-Exchange-AntiSpam-MessageData-ChunkCount:X-MS-Exchange-AntiSpam-MessageData-0:X-MS-Exchange-AntiSpam-MessageData-1; bh=vNWik9gPQj9bKtNXolztInppHglsxL21JrmRBTzr3Vc=; b=oAHHsSjfOu2Oz/A+6sUdlxSBky6XQLFOyrSHeV/f0LmTRJT9iFurZjZPkCVmnJ7TOsspq3cmqJwa9zr/uSsZpSabg70Bio9CY22ICjDcvsmR90V4rUfkkr+VNXA/6w33Yro8+Sxzj60O0PwqmTD8GQYPT12iZOj1pA/l/bWys6Bhv1DRgFPEaxtyqNr2bzMfPkrEdVswPFc2kIu1lSHuuKrl0QoQDdDsirmZf5QOx1V7KgBYTzXJ5CTxOrs7aGWA3OjpLKBQ9M4Xi8ybJeV6tOIKGGEVdTMQ8aDnj3fU9TYoypqt9E4y+xYc5yla1LvHM+T//rJr/xc/h6pgXIdKnw==
ARC-Authentication-Results: i=2; mx.microsoft.com 1; spf=fail (sender ip is 175.100.161.140) smtp.rcpttodomain=gmail.com smtp.mailfrom=hdfcbank.com; dmarc=pass (p=reject sp=reject pct=100) action=none header.from=hdfcbank.com; dkim=pass (signature was verified) header.d=hdfcbank.com; arc=pass (0 oda=1 ltdi=1 spf=[1,1,smtp.mailfrom=hdfcbank.com] dkim=[1,1,header.d=hdfcbank.com] dmarc=[1,1,header.from=hdfcbank.com])
DKIM-Signature: v=1; a=rsa-sha256; c=relaxed/relaxed; d=hdfcbank.com; s=selector1; h=From:Date:Subject:Message-ID:Content-Type:MIME-Version:X-MS-Exchange-SenderADCheck; bh=vNWik9gPQj9bKtNXolztInppHglsxL21JrmRBTzr3Vc=; b=eq2egeJsCYoG9PDBfZDbpklnspkxvBg5h6WRUEU++gQIsmSmETSpAhI9diinWPU5r1b3pSFx25Wq7G3F78qdoG7npix4Jmlja2BUCkkvtXrJCGjveIRpSDy2g9VLrHj02YkBeMiRPXb2CpEkqcLmVzN68+efWtjuPJmH1gnHima4p5Qj1/3HjTy5BL0Uu7bFIz18XI79tXjpKeCAdXTx9cPjz0BY9D6j3i8zLpnQ5bjqToUTeeAr3ein2JEYALj+6OWEcPIqJrEwDFHmTVgGMfKZED/FBG2rn12i6wdDt3fJoIKSLLw3F40djRkUbrgZgfBhsRry/Sqp/5vuyEV27Q==
Received: from PN3PR01CA0101.INDPRD01.PROD.OUTLOOK.COM (2603:1096:c01:9b::7) by PN0PR01MB6517.INDPRD01.PROD.OUTLOOK.COM (2603:1096:c01:72::12) with Microsoft SMTP Server (version=TLS1_2, cipher=TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384) id 15.20.7249.30; Sat, 3 Feb 2024 06:35:17 +0000
Received: from PN1PEPF000062B9.INDPRD01.PROD.OUTLOOK.COM (2603:1096:c01:9b:cafe::2b) by PN3PR01CA0101.outlook.office365.com (2603:1096:c01:9b::7) with Microsoft SMTP Server (version=TLS1_2, cipher=TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384) id 15.20.7249.31 via Frontend Transport; Sat, 3 Feb 2024 06:35:17 +0000
X-MS-Exchange-Authentication-Results: spf=fail (sender IP is 175.100.161.140) smtp.mailfrom=hdfcbank.com; dkim=pass (signature was verified) header.d=hdfcbank.com;dmarc=pass action=none header.from=hdfcbank.com;
Received-SPF: Fail (protection.outlook.com: domain of hdfcbank.com does not designate 175.100.161.140 as permitted sender) receiver=protection.outlook.com; client-ip=175.100.161.140; helo=smtpout01.hdfcbank.com;
Received: from smtpout01.hdfcbank.com (175.100.161.140) by PN1PEPF000062B9.mail.protection.outlook.com (10.167.242.5) with Microsoft SMTP Server (version=TLS1_2, cipher=TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384) id 15.20.7249.19 via Frontend Transport; Sat, 3 Feb 2024 06:35:17 +0000
Received: from smtpin01.hdfcbank.com (unknown [172.16.6.26]) by smtpout01.hdfcbank.com (Postfix) with ESMTP id 3E68440151C6 for <theon@gmail.com>; Sat,
  3 Feb 2024 12:05:16 +0530 (IST)
Received: from IND01-BMX-obe.outbound.protection.outlook.com (mail-bmxind01lp2232.outbound.protection.outlook.com [104.47.74.232]) (using TLSv1.2 with cipher ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384 (256/256 bits)) (No client certificate requested) by smtpin01.hdfcbank.com (Postfix) with ESMTPS id 36B834013F36 for <theon@gmail.com>; Sat,
  3 Feb 2024 12:05:16 +0530 (IST)
ARC-Seal: i=1; a=rsa-sha256; s=arcselector9901; d=microsoft.com; cv=none; b=KOet/GEffnIdXoEhsVX/ttAgfar1nfXwp3u4nNVe+jAViXsZrt3A4G/f5JO0Gnn6OtJ/6xkE6lkFwvdcpq7VQXbEBbyiW5If4TxJblVIfe047J+8wCMdm0el5BAeCJb+fRFYmKGScu5kgL9Thpnx02Utx9pdwgCOE3x5K65WoxmKknNViDP3UdgO2dbrrfeEO2SfNzn6VDatrMd0Ke08zJVT78lejnVUwajqZJj/f34QkoPUkFB/bOK1yZ8oWLYBp7f4qIAl3cnllTb6S45xdj4bFaeuP/BPO1J4g5hQXXonGJLBl0FaVADkPYS9OGPoSqYWDeEReL6oyDq7ly6ZtQ==
ARC-Message-Signature: i=1; a=rsa-sha256; c=relaxed/relaxed; d=microsoft.com; s=arcselector9901; h=From:Date:Subject:Message-ID:Content-Type:MIME-Version:X-MS-Exchange-AntiSpam-MessageData-ChunkCount:X-MS-Exchange-AntiSpam-MessageData-0:X-MS-Exchange-AntiSpam-MessageData-1; bh=vNWik9gPQj9bKtNXolztInppHglsxL21JrmRBTzr3Vc=; b=GXLBjJnVbkAmsPCIFDi9cZUE6PKVA3bEthzOM8c7yOo6iZohiq96MrVzo1nJ8QXZiJu72A+vBpsy50nHSW/Ur9Nfnvw9cC8t6XtyPHBgoEikocXgZzHw5wnrV4w0d/mx1CZbgIl8EZySZhYHGzw23osGgE2rKFp73/ZgHJjDwBPL+o1coykICB4cmf5fve8zpcvs7YjjXtHVl+skg5k5t1Vol8MFGv5kQFEgGoNmdZ0KMrQysiDaPZV/0V70xJjL+LCV8VUwEaxXYzmZKe9HN+kxgDNhGiuNuHitypX0MiD44uUAAIYCDi0lUFSdFGnCzepPlLXW6YNJftIFRKLLNA==
ARC-Authentication-Results: i=1; mx.microsoft.com 1; spf=pass smtp.mailfrom=hdfcbank.com; dmarc=pass action=none header.from=hdfcbank.com; dkim=pass header.d=hdfcbank.com; arc=none
DKIM-Signature: v=1; a=rsa-sha256; c=relaxed/relaxed; d=hdfcbank.com; s=selector1; h=From:Date:Subject:Message-ID:Content-Type:MIME-Version:X-MS-Exchange-SenderADCheck; bh=vNWik9gPQj9bKtNXolztInppHglsxL21JrmRBTzr3Vc=; b=eq2egeJsCYoG9PDBfZDbpklnspkxvBg5h6WRUEU++gQIsmSmETSpAhI9diinWPU5r1b3pSFx25Wq7G3F78qdoG7npix4Jmlja2BUCkkvtXrJCGjveIRpSDy2g9VLrHj02YkBeMiRPXb2CpEkqcLmVzN68+efWtjuPJmH1gnHima4p5Qj1/3HjTy5BL0Uu7bFIz18XI79tXjpKeCAdXTx9cPjz0BY9D6j3i8zLpnQ5bjqToUTeeAr3ein2JEYALj+6OWEcPIqJrEwDFHmTVgGMfKZED/FBG2rn12i6wdDt3fJoIKSLLw3F40djRkUbrgZgfBhsRry/Sqp/5vuyEV27Q==
Received: from MAZPR01MB8535.INDPRD01.PROD.OUTLOOK.COM (2603:1096:a01:a8::8) by MAZPR01MB7810.INDPRD01.PROD.OUTLOOK.COM (2603:1096:a01:22::5) with Microsoft SMTP Server (version=TLS1_2, cipher=TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384) id 15.20.7249.31; Sat, 3 Feb 2024 06:35:14 +0000
Received: from MAZPR01MB8535.INDPRD01.PROD.OUTLOOK.COM ([fe80::ec74:5639:a4ff:7365]) by MAZPR01MB8535.INDPRD01.PROD.OUTLOOK.COM ([fe80::ec74:5639:a4ff:7365%6]) with mapi id 15.20.7249.027; Sat, 3 Feb 2024 06:35:08 +0000
From: Preferred-Banking <Preferredbanking@hdfcbank.com>
To: "theon@gmail.com" <theon@gmail.com>
Subject: Re: '453887996' Reg account details
Thread-Topic: '453887996' Reg account details
Thread-Index: AQHaVmshV0AcA8R+3kaJKOtaCSAzew==
Date: Sat, 3 Feb 2024 06:35:08 +0000
Message-ID: <MAZPR01MB8535EB470066858945921F82B9412@MAZPR01MB8535.INDPRD01.PROD.OUTLOOK.COM>
References: <sprcid65bcdc6b9e74e367a3304dab@sprinklr.com> <CABZZon-JhvsPTeuL=AiY-aC=pvtoV8SkU9PA5NSYfHi44XabOw@mail.gmail.com>
Accept-Language: en-US
Content-Language: en-US
X-MS-Has-Attach: 
X-MS-TNEF-Correlator: 
Authentication-Results-Original: dkim=none (message not signed) header.d=none;dmarc=none action=none header.from=hdfcbank.com;
x-ms-traffictypediagnostic: MAZPR01MB8535:EE_|MAZPR01MB7810:EE_|PN1PEPF000062B9:EE_|PN0PR01MB6517:EE_
X-MS-Office365-Filtering-Correlation-Id: 65b1ad40-28b3-4b59-011d-08dc2482493f
X-MS-Exchange-SenderADCheck: 1
X-MS-Exchange-AntiSpam-Relay: 0
X-Microsoft-Antispam-Untrusted: BCL:0;
X-Microsoft-Antispam-Message-Info-Original: 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
X-Forefront-Antispam-Report-Untrusted: CIP:255.255.255.255;CTRY:;LANG:en;SCL:1;SRV:;IPV:NLI;SFV:NSPM;H:MAZPR01MB8535.INDPRD01.PROD.OUTLOOK.COM;PTR:;CAT:NONE;SFS:(13230031)(346002)(396003)(366004)(376002)(39860400002)(136003)(230473577357003)(230922051799003)(451199024)(1690799017)(186009)(64100799003)(1800799012)(64756008)(8676002)(7116003)(8936002)(15650500001)(52536014)(2906002)(76116006)(4744005)(33656002)(5660300002)(86362001)(66946007)(66556008)(66476007)(66446008)(316002)(6916009)(478600001)(38070700009)(122000001)(166002)(38100700002)(966005)(9686003)(83380400001)(7696005)(71200400001)(6506007)(26005)(41300700001)(55016003)(19627405001);DIR:OUT;SFP:1101;
Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary="_000_MAZPR01MB8535EB470066858945921F82B9412MAZPR01MB8535INDP_"
MIME-Version: 1.0
X-MS-Exchange-Transport-CrossTenantHeadersStamped: MAZPR01MB7810
Return-Path: Preferredbanking@hdfcbank.com
X-EOPAttributedMessage: 0
X-MS-Exchange-Transport-CrossTenantHeadersStripped: PN1PEPF000062B9.INDPRD01.PROD.OUTLOOK.COM
X-MS-PublicTrafficType: Email
X-MS-Office365-Filtering-Correlation-Id-Prvs: 51970dc2-50ce-4159-6109-08dc24824423
X-Microsoft-Antispam: BCL:0;
X-Microsoft-Antispam-Message-Info: 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
X-Forefront-Antispam-Report: CIP:175.100.161.140;CTRY:IN;LANG:en;SCL:1;SRV:;IPV:CAL;SFV:NSPM;H:smtpout01.hdfcbank.com;PTR:InfoDomainNonexistent;CAT:NONE;SFS:(13230031)(4636009)(136003)(346002)(376002)(396003)(39860400002)(230473577357003)(230922051799003)(451199024)(1800799012)(82310400011)(1690799017)(7200799017)(64100799003)(186009)(40470700004)(46966006)(36840700001)(2906002)(5660300002)(15650500001)(33656002)(41300700001)(83380400001)(6506007)(55016003)(26005)(9686003)(336012)(6916009)(70206006)(478600001)(966005)(40460700003)(70586007)(7696005)(316002)(40480700001)(36860700001)(47076005)(19627405001)(82740400003)(356005)(166002)(81166007)(8400799017)(86362001)(8936002)(52536014)(8676002)(7116003)(36900700001);DIR:OUT;SFP:1101;
X-OriginatorOrg: hdfcbank.com
X-MS-Exchange-CrossTenant-OriginalArrivalTime: 03 Feb 2024 06:35:17.2513 (UTC)
X-MS-Exchange-CrossTenant-Network-Message-Id: 65b1ad40-28b3-4b59-011d-08dc2482493f
X-MS-Exchange-CrossTenant-Id: 827fd022-05a6-4e57-be9c-cc069b6ae62d
X-MS-Exchange-CrossTenant-OriginalAttributedTenantConnectingIp: TenantId=827fd022-05a6-4e57-be9c-cc069b6ae62d;Ip=[175.100.161.140];Helo=[smtpout01.hdfcbank.com]
X-MS-Exchange-CrossTenant-AuthSource: PN1PEPF000062B9.INDPRD01.PROD.OUTLOOK.COM
X-MS-Exchange-CrossTenant-AuthAs: Anonymous
X-MS-Exchange-CrossTenant-FromEntityHeader: HybridOnPrem
X-MS-Exchange-Transport-CrossTenantHeadersStamped: PN0PR01MB6517

--_000_MAZPR01MB8535EB470066858945921F82B9412MAZPR01MB8535INDP_
Content-Type: text/plain; charset="us-ascii"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable


Delivered-To: theon@gmail.com
Received: by 2002:a25:abe8:0:b0:d63:2ce2:43be with SMTP id v95csp165605ybi;
        Mon, 28 Aug 2023 03:36:55 -0700 (PDT)
X-Google-Smtp-Source: AGHT+IFmjLOiBXP13bYu11y9/LTde4W7MaorPUhPkeqi0YtRzn3OeW6eNEaNJ7hkCrB6j68WN/r0
X-Received: by 2002:a17:903:22c2:b0:1c0:8a05:f32e with SMTP id y2-20020a17090322c200b001c08a05f32emr26255644plg.23.1693219014858;
        Mon, 28 Aug 2023 03:36:54 -0700 (PDT)
ARC-Seal: i=1; a=rsa-sha256; t=1693219014; cv=none;
        d=google.com; s=arc-20160816;
        b=yepoyRowcG2XAH/ve0DLLPpDn4HCDzwoPC4E9BvBz11C29e49YeujtB0sjoa4D9gH/
         ofdYi8BfAtk67V19sSPglkznsoMG5450/4uD10ZThHiNW4csbMsoltVn7rqw4aKazo4x
         L82Pw0ISqrKAKd+o9SYvdX1ptMSLmFcK+a7bXqxyeZYyaNohid8BRhCh4Sr8CNTju+Lq
         e+KYeWKPRAPKyHOCAHR4iFOSPlaC05lYHV6HehX4+BvAvBklhvt+/BRrjpN1eTTTalHt
         93HFhMgYySYE0jW/djd/1V8g8WdvTB1+cRg1Jkg0Avg/mGHJW9dCpFDU1iz4ejw86TyR
         15cQ==
ARC-Message-Signature: i=1; a=rsa-sha256; c=relaxed/relaxed; d=google.com; s=arc-20160816;
        h=identifier:mime-version:subject:message-id:to:from:dkim-signature
         :date;
        bh=E2rtVl8VFQN19tVage32As7mfzEK1XI0nJgybAottwc=;
        fh=BKgX1OQnLmSYxt4eJwZyUMX9nCRkDTqfPNp/4NWaZCE=;
        b=wjYLIvEHVMXaepuVD32OdhXKqsN9iHxYhbJzh2sV5qK1oDzsauz5Ool3IsFm3Y4tvB
         k76lwmuL5wYnsnFogROsa2o7Gx/5hluTJx25zVDrQA+sB3CndlFieRddUIXQ0SJLSyio
         GYAirRJNSk5QidWRT4lK/PJOmVct3BedIGhq20JhaulOlNsKycfqWVLooNbBW4FvCWt2
         3esR+XoEmrOmsTA7hCdiT9tUB/zpY8Lqqe8zKv7GDfs6VSt4OfgP70OqpfnflKf1eIPx
         k9J7Ahhrxs/DbK6m93Zz/wEP3K6jQY7Z08DK3O8u5LBkw+CMun5j0m37PwzjG72Xzlka
         OQGg==
ARC-Authentication-Results: i=1; mx.google.com;
       dkim=pass header.i=@hdfcbank.net header.s=mailer2048 header.b=OByZX2l1;
       spf=pass (google.com: domain of creditcardops.maintenance@hdfcbank.net designates 202.154.160.235 as permitted sender) smtp.mailfrom=CreditCardOps.Maintenance@hdfcbank.net;
       dmarc=pass (p=REJECT sp=REJECT dis=NONE) header.from=hdfcbank.net
Return-Path: <CreditCardOps.Maintenance@hdfcbank.net>
Received: from 235.maila.powerelay.com (235.maila.powerelay.com. [202.154.160.235])
        by mx.google.com with ESMTPS id j13-20020a170903024d00b001b8805f98e9si7801930plh.452.2023.08.28.03.36.54
        for theon@gmail.com>
        (version=TLS1_3 cipher=TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 bits=256/256);
        Mon, 28 Aug 2023 03:36:54 -0700 (PDT)
Received-SPF: pass (google.com: domain of creditcardops.maintenance@hdfcbank.net designates 202.154.160.235 as permitted sender) client-ip=202.154.160.235;
Authentication-Results: mx.google.com;
       dkim=pass header.i=@hdfcbank.net header.s=mailer2048 header.b=OByZX2l1;
       spf=pass (google.com: domain of creditcardops.maintenance@hdfcbank.net designates 202.154.160.235 as permitted sender) smtp.mailfrom=CreditCardOps.Maintenance@hdfcbank.net;
       dmarc=pass (p=REJECT sp=REJECT dis=NONE) header.from=hdfcbank.net
Date: Mon, 28 Aug 2023 03:36:54 -0700 (PDT)
DKIM-Signature: v=1; a=rsa-sha256; c=relaxed/relaxed; s=mailer2048; d=hdfcbank.net; h=From:To:Message-ID:Subject:MIME-Version:Content-Type; i=CreditCardOps.Maintenance@hdfcbank.net; bh=E2rtVl8VFQN19tVage32As7mfzEK1XI0nJgybAottwc=; b=OByZX2l1Mvx5k3ccyz2zGDvfLrbQ3bqFFcudcY8yCyGFOcvmilG6vIbMk7Jt7d94xbYFAqE98QG3
   hpVdyLqNpWtnt/c1Kkel8r7D8CWdZGtbjpCGh3PuCg9HD1ZmQIotd4ACvR6wBRNEXcXtbYK8tCwl
   149JI2Mx0giq4Bor30zgZK9/7N1fB3Qv/ZD8uHcaEJynINSM82Bh1vtPUmp4r2VkEjo8262HmIXI
   uVOfh48utV/e7VWbDHc6Tl3czlECiGQ9P4sA9ezH88Jzw9nZmMaXllO0AS8PYvgNA5BnPEiVxvqN
   uxISkJ5P8pHzqx7FZbpnXcXepjeuYsX3YkNxZQ==
Received: from HBPRLNXSMTP3.localdomain (202.154.168.196) by 105.maila.powerelay.com id hthsc83539oh for <theon@gmail.com>; Mon, 28 Aug 2023 16:06:52 +0530 (envelope-from <CreditCardOps.Maintenance@hdfcbank.net>)
Received: from HBcosmosAPP48.hbctxdom.com (HBcosmosAPP48.hbctxdom.com [10.226.70.161]) by HBPRLNXSMTP3.localdomain (Postfix) with ESMTP id E1DF35E00008F for <theon@gmail.com>; Mon, 28 Aug 2023 16:06:52 +0530 (IST)
From: CreditCardOps.Maintenance@hdfcbank.net
To: theon@gmail.com
Message-ID: <860992258.75689.1693219012935.JavaMail.Poweruser@HBcosmosAPP48>
Subject: Important update about your Credit Card ending 3X7
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary="----=_Part_75686_1979132156.1693219012919"
identifier: 113065108

------=_Part_75686_1979132156.1693219012919
Content-Type: text/html; charset=Cp1252
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable



Delivered-To: theon@gmail.com
Received: by 2002:a05:6a10:20d5:b0:4f9:e01e:78e with SMTP id n21csp3196220pxc;
        Sun, 15 Oct 2023 07:37:17 -0700 (PDT)
X-Google-Smtp-Source: AGHT+IFYGUu+wcGMlH1U1NIOG4C22shnnwWqhGwrs6NKtboheHDiqGNpP3EIzZKyTDpQNrBy+z4S
X-Received: by 2002:a17:90b:4b45:b0:27d:4249:4040 with SMTP id mi5-20020a17090b4b4500b0027d42494040mr3851188pjb.43.1697380637155;
        Sun, 15 Oct 2023 07:37:17 -0700 (PDT)
ARC-Seal: i=1; a=rsa-sha256; t=1697380637; cv=none;
        d=google.com; s=arc-20160816;
        b=jQyoJ80861IEZyfdAJsp3D6Mi+S2oGH/WgYCMGo3kJe7HQU7WJD+Pvg7tftL3FKxtQ
         +QlupQNbktpjAGmT/Tf1BxV3AIE/+lunP866yTdof15ul7oLR1rer6jhdFgH0IMWtuW+
         7Uhb9lY3/mFVA6A5iDiMUd3SpGeCuzeQ7AHpPiV6oQVlslTZRt7dMLt/HBTJPB9+LgPm
         KuBcTHxx2mjziSZrCa71s+1FsDyePDwSo6MKiAJfSIAdVeK++pAcIXK6Jx7n6u+kCRU+
         pIF+gqy7Mp7OXWA+OiBXuwrXmK9vCLlbDR8b/peu6nA5dMWtHOtKfFMXkzeUQfmklOW6
         5U2g==
ARC-Message-Signature: i=1; a=rsa-sha256; c=relaxed/relaxed; d=google.com; s=arc-20160816;
        h=list-unsubscribe:feedback-id:envelope-to:delivery-date:nrk:rowkey
         :precedence:auto-submitted:content-transfer-encoding:mime-version
         :date:subject:to:from:reply-to:message-id:dkim-signature:dkim-filter;
        bh=nUAX9XPGxF1Igs+qKTyR2FO/GDyiguWLhayONGnpFOM=;
        fh=Aadclb46CpOuM4wWhTeN5fscxJtQnYw2y6ObhiUSOr8=;
        b=PPZPY3Nozo5d0qRJO1KZlb9YbHZIwO2iZ5hibi4by30gIVwxgNS+GMVOjmcfAYyWzK
         8UJpvbWN/1Mx3Jrc1Lw6jihhsXtI1H39WhqxTmfTZeDYO4/1BQ7fyv/OCnDuMlIv+I8O
         UThNHsYuBMnixD1n+/XT6Lnm+vH8zfhJEtNjIjHwlfhh7Mg3TbidktY2FxwBNC8qkexS
         U3GcC3aBLSNVYrAePUQuKtTFYgub9VPBtMytMKXU8eUjKjTVrL39HrkBLijr379/kf9j
         jwoqXK0/RbFljpr8bxKDMJ7ZlQ4nbpxhKKK1rnUlC6ZdhhrSh2F6lMZFsxwXwzbFOyj/
         /rvg==
ARC-Authentication-Results: i=1; mx.google.com;
       dkim=pass header.i=@hdfcbank.net header.s=mail2 header.b=KtQPqGC2;
       spf=pass (google.com: domain of edm-00huefte5ejbl6qjr@res165.hdfcbank.net designates 103.214.133.166 as permitted sender) smtp.mailfrom=edm-00hUeFTE5ejBL6QJR@res165.hdfcbank.net;
       dmarc=pass (p=REJECT sp=REJECT dis=NONE) header.from=hdfcbank.net
Return-Path: <edm-00hUeFTE5ejBL6QJR@res165.hdfcbank.net>
Received: from res166.hdfcbank.net (res166.hdfcbank.net. [103.214.133.166])
        by mx.google.com with ESMTPS id j5-20020a17090aeb0500b00277651787f1si4163811pjz.145.2023.10.15.07.37.16
        for <theon@gmail.com>
        (version=TLS1_2 cipher=ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256 bits=128/128);
        Sun, 15 Oct 2023 07:37:17 -0700 (PDT)
Received-SPF: pass (google.com: domain of edm-00huefte5ejbl6qjr@res165.hdfcbank.net designates 103.214.133.166 as permitted sender) client-ip=103.214.133.166;
Authentication-Results: mx.google.com;
       dkim=pass header.i=@hdfcbank.net header.s=mail2 header.b=KtQPqGC2;
       spf=pass (google.com: domain of edm-00huefte5ejbl6qjr@res165.hdfcbank.net designates 103.214.133.166 as permitted sender) smtp.mailfrom=edm-00hUeFTE5ejBL6QJR@res165.hdfcbank.net;
       dmarc=pass (p=REJECT sp=REJECT dis=NONE) header.from=hdfcbank.net
Received: from hbomniprodapp8.domain (unknown [175.100.163.10]) by res165.hdfcbank.net (Postfix) with ESMTPSA id 8D288C2F3B84 for <theon@gmail.com>; Sun, 15 Oct 2023 20:07:15 +0530 (IST)
DKIM-Filter: OpenDKIM Filter v2.11.0 res165.hdfcbank.net 8D288C2F3B84
DKIM-Signature: v=1; a=rsa-sha256; c=relaxed/simple; d=hdfcbank.net; s=mail2; t=1697380635; bh=G/BgHuiF6+WY9e7H/Ex5jrMoK4gr5lGjXc4o4r65rO0=; h=Message-ID:From:To:Subject:Date:From:Sender:To:CC:Subject:
     Message-Id:Date; b=KtQPqGC2hQCbXbqQZLED7+ol0mR5QUgKU+EB7o5+6QfwkmGyV8HoR+wghG3bkRaQH
     Us1AY8YlaRBDNsiDaNsiVjcb0N+7nVjaWBJ5tYA4bFycXtV5d0a3vHn/mQaDCgFjtI
     1aURo0fT3eazc1diU7H1+bJe4b1GdxJQdqE0EtiBiF+3Qs1KSsmtUszjXChv6F2+S4
     GR3xZU5j0QTnh61npSMYG4z/FJRCOQb1KPgrNxbF5sQx0VdRAWuUQeKpy3kUi0E+yj
     imqBvM4ggOl76u8Rfo2Qq2BadtUADp7mzn4GYJIeH6ORR//MZCh3+VRmNxQaOV2wpU
     yoNuB+80rACuA==
Message-ID: <4a89e8aa008beb241638d0b213e45c77@hdfcbank.net>
Reply-To: HDFC Bank <information@hdfcbank.net>
From: HDFC Bank <information@hdfcbank.net>
To: <theon@gmail.com>
Subject: Urgent attention! Your  bank credit card will be closed on 21-Jan-24!
Date: Sun, 15 Oct 2023 20:07:12 +0530
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/html; charset="utf-8"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable
Auto-Submitted: auto-generated
Precedence: bulk
RowKey: camp-00b4e220-6121-4a93-a63f-d0848bd73506_e089a214-75e0-489f-a1a7-7a4944395048_BL6QJR_651eaac2-faa6-4868-a404-fcd93548ec30_20231015080712
NRK: 00hUeFTE5ejBL6QJR
Delivery-date: 10/15/2023 12:00:00 AM
Envelope-to: information@hdfcbank.net
X-Priority: 3
Feedback-ID: TE5:BL6QJR:ej:hUe
List-Unsubscribe: <mailto:abuse@res165.hdfcbank.net?subject=00hUeFTE5ejBL6QJR>
X-Abuse-Reports-To: <mailto:abuse@res165.hdfcbank.net?subject=00hUeFTE5ejBL6QJR>




Delivered-To: theon@gmail.com
Received: by 2002:adf:a1c3:0:b0:337:4d85:da74 with SMTP id v3csp1284061wrv;
        Wed, 24 Jan 2024 21:37:58 -0800 (PST)
X-Google-Smtp-Source: AGHT+IGpbLRGcqZvHMUGEWPG4zFkbeKzT6ozJQliGMTUPasKwZ2Uk4Lvw/M2Fpdc3DWqNvII32Tw
X-Received: by 2002:a0c:df11:0:b0:683:6873:d63e with SMTP id g17-20020a0cdf11000000b006836873d63emr1132556qvl.39.1706161078305;
        Wed, 24 Jan 2024 21:37:58 -0800 (PST)
ARC-Seal: i=1; a=rsa-sha256; t=1706161078; cv=none;
        d=google.com; s=arc-20160816;
        b=RnTaRuB1akE4/HWxg3DWUjCd1iXC5kIO2cr3T/pgz6q8avp4o3vTDiJIHJxJKfkB2k
         X4a6OdIBcbVbqji7xq6OPr+G2vg9qWgC1js02NdtXzTrVC4JX0U0qvNg6QZbeLBZQ/pG
         K6DbcFUwKXO+ihep1YUZvBKQG9WpjQ1fxLGO1fdZMD3gRSNLqDeJXWDti8wATs92chkn
         ESVOpX3v4hEtc1ka7u1ir579ROe2mbtxYJluk2TqC+7Kfc7aGLvGw6AFlH4CZ4RMrSZY
         A9buBZZb2QhUleb/RPvkENwokvgwnODLmFSrcSBWNV8uc9PdpT6gp3Sju8vr6bhdZfTQ
         dxTg==
ARC-Message-Signature: i=1; a=rsa-sha256; c=relaxed/relaxed; d=google.com; s=arc-20160816;
        h=mime-version:to:message-id:subject:date:from:dkim-signature;
        bh=ssRapEDxoSkK6OHaosjSP5BVE9lXQB5fdtEG1qubv/E=;
        fh=BKgX1OQnLmSYxt4eJwZyUMX9nCRkDTqfPNp/4NWaZCE=;
        b=SdUj7PrtzUedqZH1DYU+9DyXVkBtp7TIP2pOEyPlc4UNfNLhvkVcpy/9EEAwwJO6J0
         dbzZpzQAgTYOgxvPwWFT25FYXOZp3DcdpdXoP//9+CqkJ4QDTqDAL0Xu1s/0qVvqVchj
         mkUQoQGIV9WqU30ayCj1PeeMBV7zMJVhR3ZXxGuZj/M013Zyaz4rm7P0ic+SX5LUlUMa
         /vrM0WsEQ/WmkiJeQ2wzOqYNEabPvg2xVb1A+SzNGfcTprNR47viyz2p/ILN4SRr3gYF
         EB+tT5oPQuOgFbriZFSmwnz/D9SumFXE2tUOR6EtfPmbOoUZRb7eo2IKE1mIBuMIuUhu
         ihAw==
ARC-Authentication-Results: i=1; mx.google.com;
       dkim=pass header.i=@microsoft.com header.s=s1024-meo header.b="hp6ag/BV";
       spf=pass (google.com: domain of azure-noreply@microsoft.com designates 20.51.6.32 as permitted sender) smtp.mailfrom=azure-noreply@microsoft.com;
       dmarc=pass (p=REJECT sp=REJECT dis=NONE) header.from=microsoft.com
Return-Path: <azure-noreply@microsoft.com>
Received: from mail-nam-cu03-ch.northcentralus.cloudapp.azure.com (mail-nam-cu03-ch.northcentralus.cloudapp.azure.com. [20.51.6.32])
        by mx.google.com with ESMTPS id k18-20020a0cf292000000b00683a93c788dsi11640257qvl.380.2024.01.24.21.37.57
        for <theon@gmail.com>
        (version=TLS1_3 cipher=TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 bits=256/256);
        Wed, 24 Jan 2024 21:37:58 -0800 (PST)
Received-SPF: pass (google.com: domain of azure-noreply@microsoft.com designates 20.51.6.32 as permitted sender) client-ip=20.51.6.32;
Authentication-Results: mx.google.com;
       dkim=pass header.i=@microsoft.com header.s=s1024-meo header.b="hp6ag/BV";
       spf=pass (google.com: domain of azure-noreply@microsoft.com designates 20.51.6.32 as permitted sender) smtp.mailfrom=azure-noreply@microsoft.com;
       dmarc=pass (p=REJECT sp=REJECT dis=NONE) header.from=microsoft.com
DKIM-Signature: v=1; a=rsa-sha256; d=microsoft.com; s=s1024-meo; c=relaxed/relaxed; i=familysafety@microsoft.com; t=1706161077; h=from:subject:date:message-id:to:mime-version:content-type; bh=ssRapEDxoSkK6OHaosjSP5BVE9lXQB5fdtEG1qubv/E=; b=hp6ag/BVH2QQW/Z+zB08AYonfVvISy25GqXFt/d1YcTWT5hSNX0EzDa0XTx+zZCiAA9x32+IUOm YwRsCAjIVBcXxZW140MPWZSkacKJL7UTQCSoKy7OBJQJEA6aXguFuGfsi2JZhYGYiqDN6gXsMp14D sbl1fQYqS3E9dRmXN8g=
From: Microsoft Family Safety <familysafety@microsoft.com>
Date: Thu, 25 Jan 2024 05:37:57 +0000
Subject: Action required: Update your Family Safety preferences
Message-Id: <47760c3b-6a6a-4e39-ae86-c939f1ff744a@az.northcentralus.microsoft.com>
To: theon@gmail.com
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary="=-VjXmz75rShg/1Ulepiu7Mw=="

--=-VjXmz75rShg/1Ulepiu7Mw==
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable
```

Comment: Welcome to the community. Would you at least please format the headers? And I recommend censoring some of the info

Comment: Thank you. Email ID is dummy.

Comment: This is not what we do here. We'd be flooded with random emails. There are many online tools for this, like: https://mxtoolbox.com/EmailHeaders.aspx

Comment: @schroeder: While these tools translate the header in a human readable form (i.e. DMARC passed etc) they leave the interpretation what this means to the user. They (and most online sources propagating DMARC) usually don't talk about the limitations of DMARC, i.e. granularity domain only, no guarantee to be from the actual domain owner but might be from a service provider etc

Comment: @SteffenUllrich yep, but we are not a header parsing service

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that one can rely on the value of `Authentication-Results` (which can be done if this mail was taken directly from the gmail account) then nothing here suggests sender spoofing. Specifically the DMARC information in `Authentication-Results` show that the mail is sent from the domain which is claimed as sender domain in the From-header.

No further information can be retrieved from this header or any other header though. Specifically one can not conclude that the mail was sent from the claimed specific account in the domain - DMARC does not provide this granularity. Nor can one assume that the sender's account wasn't compromised. It might also be that the mail wasn't sent from the company directly but instead but some service provider, which was granted by the company the right to send mails in the name of the company. There is currently no way to have more granular restrictions on what mails can be sent and from which specific accounts, and then verify that a received mails upholds to these restrictions.

Comment: Thank you Steffen. What about the email header at the bottom of the post, from microsoft.

Comment: @TheonFrey: same

Comment: So, we can conclude that the emails are not spoofed. Is there any way a person can spoof emails with/without changing the body of the email but the email header looks legit as the original sender. I have been getting emails where the body of the email is changed but the header looks legit (so i can say the emails are spoofed). This includes few of my other bank accounts.

Comment: @TheonFrey: Please read carefully about the limitations I've mentioned. We can only conclude that the **domain** in From is very likely not spoofed, i.e. that the sender had the ability to send verified mail with this **domain**. It might be a different account or a compromised sender. And there are techniques to add to the body and still keep the DKIM signature intact, but these require insecure features of the signature (notably use of `l` attribute) which are not used here - see https://noxxi.de/research/breaking-dkim-on-purpose-and-by-chance.html for details.

Comment: Thank You Steffen. I read your article, and I couldn't find the l attribute in the email header. Say if a person has control over your home network remotely, is it possible to control the emails (like deleting it before it reaches your device, altering the email content. Any other way apart from this is it possible to control the emails without changing the header.

Comment: @TheonFrey: Body and header are a single document. If one can be changed both can be. The DKIM signature says that an MTA responsible for the specific domain given in the signature has signed it and this includes integrity of the body (apart from when `l` is used, which means only partial integrity). An attacker could not replace the body without also replacing the DKIM signature, or the validation will fail (which you need to check if they match). The attacker cannot create their own signature for the domain, but could use previous content with previous signature.

Comment: I see the spoofed email DKIM signature has q=dns/txt; c=relaxed/simple and these attributes t=1687939176; h=From:Date:Mime-Version:Message-Id:To:Subject:Content-Type; different from the genuine email. Does this confirm the email is indeed spoofed?

Comment: @TheonFrey: *"Does this confirm the email is indeed spoofed?"* - No. Its just a differently configured DKIM setup. You might notice that the  DKIM selector and SPF IP addresses are different - this looks like a service provider authorized to send mails in the name of the bank.